# why is a simple struct field type not supported in GAE datastore?

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore

[my unit test](https://github.com/0xor1/gus/blob/master/gus_test.go#L19) is failing with message:

> &errors.errorString{s:"datastore: unsupported struct field type: sus.Version"}

I have a test struct type that I am trying to save to GAE datastore:

```
type foo struct{
    sus.Version
}
```

where sus.Version is the interface:

```
type Version interface{
    GetVersion() int
    getVersion() int
    incrementVersion() 
    decrementVersion() 
}
```

I have tried running my test with two Version implementations, first where it is just an alias for an int:

```
type version int
```

and secondly as a struct:

```
type version struct{
    val int
}
```

where the Version interface methods are given receiver type `(v *version)`, it needs to be a pointer so decrement and increment actually update the version they are called on and not just a copy. I'm not sure why this isn't working, potentially because it's an anonymous field? or perhaps because it's a pointer to an int or struct rather than an actual int or struct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [datastore package](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference) doesn't allow all types to be used. In particular, it only allows the following types to be used:

```
- signed integers (int, int8, int16, int32 and int64),
- bool,
- string,
- float32 and float64,
- []byte (up to 1 megabyte in length),
- any type whose underlying type is one of the above predeclared types,
- ByteString,
- *Key,
- time.Time (stored with microsecond precision),
- appengine.BlobKey,
- appengine.GeoPoint,
- structs whose fields are all valid value types,
- slices of any of the above.
```

Note that this doesn't include "any interface type".